# How to replace text inside curly brackets when user types in input box react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, replace

The issue is i have a string that is suppose
My name is {{firstName}}.

and i have an input box what i want is whenever user types in the input box i want to replace the {{firstName}} with that input value and change it as user types.

The current problem is i am using replaceAll("{{firstName}}",inputValue);
inputValue is the state i am storing in react onChange.

but as soon as {{firstName}} is replaced with inputValue there is no way to update the value that is in place of {{firstName}}.

I am doing it dynamically in react. What i mean by this is i have array of variables for that i am creating input for all of them so whenever user types in any of the corresponding data changes in the string for ex

input for first name that changes.   My name is {{firstName}}
input for last name that changes.  My name is {{firstName}} {{lastName}}
input for email that changes. This is my {{email}} email.I tried replaceAll but i cannot think of a way that will keep track of that changed value as i have alot of inputs i cannot maintain state for all of them.

[Here is the example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57sTZ.png)

the variable 1 will update {{1}} on the right side and variable 2 will {{2}}.

Comment: can you post some code relevant to this problem. It will be helpful to solve your issue.

Comment: How are you storing/modifying the template string?

Comment: Retain the original template string somewhere (in the DOM or in your Javascript) so you can use it again the second time.  The details of how best to do this depend upon the code and HTML you have which you are not showing us.  Please show your existing code and HTML so we can advise more specifically.  Questions here should ALWAYS show your existing code to make a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Christopher I have a template the user can update by typing inside the input box. The template I am using is from Zoko.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use onchange and useState for example like this :

```
function MyApp() {

  const [name , setName] = useState('')

  function handleChange(event) {
    setName(event.target.value)
  }
  
  return (
    <>
     <input name="name" onChange={handleChange} />
     <p>dynamic name {name}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```